# Not Going in update profile method (error Trying to get property of non-object )(Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have write new method in laravel resource Contrller and now trying to access that method but its not going there my form action is as

```
<form action="/user/updateprofile/{{$user->id}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="hidden" id="action" value="profile">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="user-id" value="{{$user->id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

i have define my routes as for usercontroller

```
Route::get('user/profile/{id}', ['as' => 'user.profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@profile']);
Route::get('edit/update/{id}', 'UserController@updateprofile');
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
```

method in controller is as

```
public function updateprofile(Request $request, $id)
{
    return ('Here');
}
```

what to do how to fix
when i click submit button it should go in **updateprofile** method in UserController
What the issue is here please help me to fix

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `::put` route:

```
Route::put('user/updateprofile/{id}', 'UserController@updateprofile');
```

Comment: What does `{{ dd($user) }}` show if you put this before your form?

Comment: where should i do this @alexey mezenin

Comment: @recoverymen before `<form ...` it will show you an object or `null`, please tell me what does it show so I could help.

Comment: It shows the all value which we have in edit form now i want to save these value which we can if i go in updateprofile method in userController

Comment: @recoverymen, if you see this error when you press submit button, you should show us all your routes. If you see the error where you should see the form, then please show contents of this blade file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Route::put()`

HTML forms do not support `PUT`

So you have to do something like:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

And i routes:

`Route::put('user/updateprofile/{id}', 'UserController@updateprofile');`

Comment: what is /foo/bar here in action? @Dip

Comment: In form action you should have :

action="{{ action('UserController@updateprofile') }}"

Answer (score 0):

You should change in first linee `['as' => 'user.profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@updateprofile']` , change profile to update profile because your action name is updateprofile.